# settext force close when trying to display text in textview

Tags: java, android, settext, forceclose

This is the Main java file,i was trying to use the `settext` method but everytime i use it it gives me  force close

```
  public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    TextView myAwesomeTextView;

         @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

       myAwesomeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myAwesomeTextView);
       myAwesomeTextView.setText("My Awesome Text");


    }
   }
```

**XML**

```
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
   android:id="@+id/myAwesomeTextView"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="s"
   android:textSize="20sp"
   android:editable="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

this is my first app so i dont know much about android i searched alot but i coudnt fix it hence i asked the best group.thankyou

**Logcat**

```
12-13 12:21:37.946  29196-29196/eu.itcsolutions.android.tutorial D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
12-13 12:21:37.947  29196-29196/eu.itcsolutions.android.tutorial E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: eu.itcsolutions.android.tutorial, PID: 29196
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{eu.itcsolutions.android.tutorial/eu.itcsolutions.android.tutorial.SecondActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
            at eu.itcsolutions.android.tutorial.SecondActivity.onCreate(SecondActivity.java:47)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
12-13 12:21:39.658  29196-29196/eu.itcsolutions.android.tutorial I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 29196 SIG: 9
```

Comment: can you please post error log ?

Comment: Without knowing what is error we can not guide.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/7R7cHtp5 is this it?

Comment: is this it?http://pastebin.com/7R7cHtp5

Comment: thankyou! any solution for the problem?

Comment: you have used `setContentView(R.layout.main)` but you have defined `TextView` in `second.xml`, so just change `setContentView(R.layout.main)` to `setContentView(R.layout.second)` as i have answered.

Comment: @ShalomMathews if you find solution then either put it as a answer or accept right answer.

Comment: @DhavalGondaliya your answer was right i clicked the check option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `setContentView(R.layout.second)` instead of `setContentView(R.layout.main)`.

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    TextView myAwesomeTextView;

         @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);

       myAwesomeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myAwesomeTextView);
       myAwesomeTextView.setText("My Awesome Text");


    }
   }
```